# Spring beans load sequence in Maven Overlay projects

Tags: xml, spring, maven, overlay

I have a Maven Overlay project that is utilizing Struts and Spring.

I am using the Spring Extension Object to extend a business object to provide some additional functionality.
Also, I am overriding several beans from the business object.
To do this I created 3 Spring Config Files -

DevelopmentProposal.xml (Business Object name - only contains the  element and the attribute definition where I define my lookup and inquiry definitions)

DevelopmentProposalOverrides.xml (Copied specific beans from the original 
DevelopmentProposal.xml file and changed label names, etc...)

DevelopmentProposalExtension (Defined my new attributes for my extension here)

To do all this I setup my custom datadictionary directory (where all my XML files reside) and pointed my CustomSpringBeans.xml at this directory using the `dataDictionaryPackages` property.

This all was working up until yesterday when I did an SVN update on my src repository on the app server and all of a sudden all my overrides stopped working.  The extension is still working though, just my overrides are affected.

After inspecting the web server logs files I noticed that my changes to the beans in my overlay WERE getting picked up, but right after, the beans from the default project were getting loaded thus clobbering my changes.

The bizarre thing about all this is that on my Windows Development environment - everything is working!  (Windows 7, Tomcat 6.0.x, Java 1.7.x)

It is NOT working on the application server (Linux RedHat Box).

Question -

Does this sound more like an environmental issue or is this a problem most likely with my Spring config files and how I have them setup which is dictating a different load sequence (which happens to work in development environment)?

Any help / advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to post some actual code...not enough to go on to figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: This has been resolved. Problem was with the environment (running a VM).  I switched to a new server and the problem went away.  Since then I trashed the old VM and I'm continuing to use the new one.  Very strange behavior.